# Proof of Gauss theorem (divergence theorem) in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve an exercise in where it is asked to show the divergence theorem, or also known as Gauss theorem, in $\mathbb R^2$ using Green's theorem.

I suppose that the divergence theorem in $\mathbb R^2$ is that for a $C^1$ vector field $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined on a $3$ type region $D$ such that $\partial D$ is a closed curve, we have $$\iint_D div(F)dA=\int_{\partial D} Fds$$

I've tried to prove this theorem applying Green's theorem but I coudn't, I would appreciate if someone could provide a solution using Green's theorem (or at least the steps I should follow to prove the equality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall Green's theorem
$$\int_{\partial D} F ds=\int_{\partial D}F_1 dx+F_2 dy=\iint_D (\partial F_2/\partial x-\partial F_1/\partial y)dxdy$$
From this, setting $G_1=-F_2$ and $G_2=F_1$, we get 
$$\iint_D (\partial F_1/\partial x+\partial F_2/\partial y)dxdy=\iint_D (\partial G_2/\partial x-\partial G_1/\partial y)dxdy=$$$$\int_{\partial D} G_1 dx+G_2dy=\int_{\partial D} -F_2 dx+F_1 dy$$
So $$\iint_D\text{div} Fdxdy=\int_{\partial D} F\cdot\mathbf{n} ds$$
where $\mathbf{n}$ is an outward unit normal vector to $\partial D$.

Notice that this is not the theorem you stated!

Comment: Seems to me that there is _quite a number of typos_ in there. Please improve ! (Could have done it for you but then I don't know if I'm not going to distort your argument a great deal)

Comment: @HandeBruijn did you notice something more significant than the missing $dxdy$s I've just fixed?

Comment: Nope. And now I see the logic too (+1).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the normal in your calculation. Green's theorem says that $$\iint_D (Q_x-P_y)dxdy=\int_{\partial D}Pdx+Qdy$$

Consider the form $\omega=-Qdx+Pdy$. Then $d\omega=(P_x+Q_y)dx\wedge dy$, i.e. if $F=(P,Q)$ then $dw=({\rm div\;}F)dx\wedge dy$. Thus the above says that $$\iint_D {\rm div }\; F dxdy=\int_{\partial D}(-Qdx+Pdy)$$

Now suppose $\partial D$ is parametrized by $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$. Then the derivative is $\gamma'(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$ and the normal is ${\bf n}(t)=(\gamma_2(t),-\gamma_1(t))/\lVert \gamma'(t)\rVert$. Now $$\begin{align}\int_{\partial D}(-Qdx+Pdy)&=\int_0^1 Q(\gamma(t))(-\gamma_1'(t))+P(\gamma(t))\gamma_2'(t)dt\\&=\int_0^1 F(\gamma(t))\cdot {\bf n}(t)\lVert \gamma'(t)\rVert dt\\&=\int_{\partial D}(F\cdot{\bf n})ds\end{align}$$

which is what you wanted. You can do this in three dimensions too, by using the form $\star \omega=Pdy\wedge dz+Qdz\wedge dx+Rdx\wedge dy$, i.e. applying the Hodge star to $\omega =Pdx+Qdy+Rdz$. Then $d(\star \omega)={\rm div}\,F \; dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ where $F=(P,Q,R)$, and if $\rho:[0,1]\times [0,1] \to\Bbb R^3$ $(s,t)\mapsto \rho(s,t)$ is a parametrization of the boundary of your body, using the normal $\rho_s \times \rho_t$, tortuous calculations will show that $$\iint_{\partial B} \star \omega=\iint_{\partial B} F\cdot {\bf n} dS$$ where the latter is a surface integral.

Comment: Your answer may be correct. But how do you think a beginner is going to absorb your overly complicated notations ?

Comment: Dear @HandeBruijn, what notation strikes you as overly complicated?

Comment: Just take a look at the answer by Kevin Carlson. Does it have to be more complicated than that?

Comment: @HandeBruijn Kevin's answer glosses over the details. But you haven't told me what you think is overly complicated yet.

Comment: In my opinion Kevin's answer is just simple, straightforward and to the point, almost in the style I would have been done it myself.

Comment: @han Ok. I was trying to understand your objection, but it seems the objection is "...look at Kevin's answer. Now look at yours."